# Hibernate Spring BeanInstanciationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

I have made some improvements to the code which I think it's better than the previous but after running it I'm getting this error:
controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveCyclosUsers")
    public ModelAndView saveCyclosUsersCreditLimit(@ModelAttribute("cyclosUsers") Float cyclosUsersCreditLimit, BindingResult bindingResult)
    {
        cyclosUsersService.saveCyclosUsersCreditLimit(cyclosUsersCreditLimit);
        System.out.println("Cyclos Users List");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:cyclosUsersList.html");   
    }
```

The DAO code:

```
@Override
    public void saveCyclosUsersCreditLimit(Float cyclosUsersCreditLimit) {
        Object acceptCreditLimit = null;
        acceptCreditLimit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("UPDATE Cyclos30.accounts SET credit_limit =" +"WEB-INF.views.Register.cyclosUsersCreditLimit.value" +" " 
                                                                              +"WHERE owner_name =" +"WEB-INF.views.Register.ownerName.selectedItem");
        if(acceptCreditLimit != null)
        {
            try
            {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(acceptCreditLimit);
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The jsp code:

```
<tr>
                    <td><form:label path="cyclosUsersCreditLimit" name = "cyclosUsersCreditLimit">Enter an Amount:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="cyclosUsersCreditLimit" name = "cyclosUsersCreditLimit"/></td>
                </tr>
```

This is the error log. Though i understand a bit about what the complaint is all about but I cannot figure it out what exactly I'm to do.

```
 Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.lang.Float]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Float.<init>()

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.lang.Float]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Float.<init>()
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.lang.Float]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Float.<init>()
        org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:659)
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:293)
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:163)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Try changing this - @ModelAttribute("cyclosUsers") Float cyclosUsersCreditLimit to @ModelAttribute("cyclosUsers") float cyclosUsersCreditLimit.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error.